# Haskell "import qualified" and "Not in scope: data constructor"

Tags: haskell

I have an import like this:

```
import qualified Bioinformatics.DNA as DNA
```

from an other file looking like this:

```
data DNA = A | C | G | T
    deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)
```

And in this function in the module RNA where:

```
module Bioinformatics.RNA
  ( RNA
  , fromDna
  ) where

import qualified Bioinformatics.DNA as DNA

data RNA = A | C | G | U
    deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)

fromDna :: DNA.DNA -> RNA
fromDna DNA.A = A
fromDna DNA.C = C
fromDna DNA.G = G
fromDna DNA.T = U
```

I receive errors:

```
/home/thibaud/code/bioinformatics/src/Bioinformatics/RNA.hs:46:9:
    Not in scope: data constructor ‘DNA.A’

/home/thibaud/code/bioinformatics/src/Bioinformatics/RNA.hs:47:9:
    Not in scope: data constructor ‘DNA.C’

/home/thibaud/code/bioinformatics/src/Bioinformatics/RNA.hs:48:9:
    Not in scope: data constructor ‘DNA.G’

/home/thibaud/code/bioinformatics/src/Bioinformatics/RNA.hs:49:9:
    Not in scope: data constructor ‘DNA.T’
```

Do you have an idea why?
Thanks

Comment: You probably don't need the `data A ; ...; data T` type definitions. The value constructors are enough, provided you export and import them as pointed out in the answer below.

Answer (score 3):

Use `(..)`  to import all the constructors of a data type.

```
import qualified Bioinformatics.DNA as DNA (DNA(..), A, C, G, T)
```

**Code Breakdown**

EDIT:  Let's break down your code a little since its not quite idiomatic.

```
import qualified Bioinformatics.DNA as DNA (DNA(..), A, C, G, T)
```

That's already an odd one. Typically people import things qualified or selectively, not both.  Try just:

```
import qualified Bioinfomatics.DNA as DNA
```

So lets keep the quantification and drop the explicit list of symbols.

Now for the use, you have:

```
fromDna :: DNA.DNA -> RNA
fromDna DNA.A = A
fromDna DNA.C = C
fromDna DNA.G = G
fromDna DNA.T = U
```

The claim that this function converts from DNA to RNA.  Note your questino never presented an RNA type or constructors - are those in your code somewhere?  The remaining error from the code you posted is with respect to RNA, consider something like:

```
import qualified Bioinformatics.RNA as RNA

fromDna :: DNA.DNA -> RNA.RNA
fromDna DNA.A = RNA.A
fromDna DNA.C = RNA.C
fromDna DNA.G = RNA.G
fromDna DNA.T = RNA.U
```

Comment: it's not working with DNA(..), I get the same errors…

Comment: Are you sure?  You should be getting different errors now, such as `"Not in scope 'A' Perhaps you ment one of these: 'DNA.A' ..."`.  After that's done you'll probably get a type error with expected type vs actual type DNA/RNA.

Comment: I updated my first post with the modification for the import and the definition of RNA type.

Comment: The OP is already importing everything from `Bioinformatics.DNA`, so it must be an issue with the export list of that module.

Comment: @ReidBarton Right!  @Thibaud I see your RNA export list is `RNA` instead of `RNA(..)`, do you do the same thing in DNA?  You need to export the constructors.  Also, this question is a case-study in why you should paste a complete example and not fragments.

Answer (score 3):

Let's imagine we need a `Geometry.Shape` module for operations on a shapes. First, we'll make a folder called `Geometry`. Mind the capital `G`. In it, we'll place the `Shape.hs` file. Here's what the file will contain:

```
module Geometry.Shape
  ( Shape(Circle,Rectangle)
  , Point
  ) where

data Point = Point Float Float deriving (Show)
data Shape = Circle Point Float | Rectangle Point Point deriving (Show)
```

*Notice that when defining a point, we used the same name for the data type and the value constructor.*

So let's assume that we need the `Geometry` module for various geometric calculations. We will create the `Geometry.hs` file and place it at the same level as the `Geometry` directory:

```
module Geometry (area) where

import qualified Geometry.Shape as Shape

area :: Shape.Shape -> Float
area (Shape.Circle _ r) = pi * r ^ 2
area (Shape.Rectangle (Shape.Point x1 y1) (Shape.Point x2 y2)) =
    (abs $ x2 - x1) * (abs $ y2 - y1)
```

The file structure should now look like this:

```
.
├── Geometry
│   └── Shape.hs
└── Geometry.hs
```

Well, let's check our `area` function. First we need to open GHCi in the same directory as the `Geometry.hs` file.

```
$ ghci
GHCi, version 7.10.3: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Prelude>
```

Then let's load `Geometry` module:

```
Prelude> :l Geometry.hs
[1 of 2] Compiling Geometry.Shape   ( Geometry/Shape.hs, interpreted )
[2 of 2] Compiling Geometry         ( Geometry.hs, interpreted )

Geometry.hs:7:24: Not in scope: data constructor ‘Shape.Point’

Geometry.hs:7:44: Not in scope: data constructor ‘Shape.Point’
Failed, modules loaded: Geometry.Shape.
```

Oops! Something went wrong. But wait! Look again at the error message:

> Not in scope: data constructor ‘Shape.Point’

Well, simply speaking, it means that the type constructor is not in the reachable scope. So let's fix it by changing the `Shape.hs` file as follows:

```
module Geometry.Shape
  ( Shape(Circle,Rectangle)
  , Point(..)
  ) where
```

Notice we changed `Point` to `Point(..)`. Reload module as follows:

```
Prelude> :r
[1 of 2] Compiling Geometry.Shape   ( Geometry/Shape.hs, interpreted )
[2 of 2] Compiling Geometry         ( Geometry.hs, interpreted )
Ok, modules loaded: Geometry, Geometry.Shape.
```

and test it:

```
Prelude> area (Shape.Circle (Shape.Point 0 0) 24)
1809.5574
```

Yay, it works! I want to draw your attention to the fact that we used `(..)` to import all the constructors of the `Point` data type. It's the same as writing `Point (Point)`. Similarly, we could use `Shape(..)` instead of `Shape(Circle,Rectangle)`. For more see: https://www.haskell.org/tutorial/modules.html

Not exporting the value constructors of a data types makes them more abstract in such a way that we hide their implementation. Also, whoever uses our module can't pattern match against the value constructors. This is why previously we get compilation error in the `Geometry` module.

I hope this example will help you understand the reason for such errors.